# How a regex would look like if I want to use it for temperature? (Celcius)

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I want to write a validator in flutter for temperature input.

These are the options: 0, 0.5, 1.5, 10.5, -10.5 -1.5, -0.5

But I can't find out how should the regex look like.

```
  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(
          r"(.\\d\\d.\\d)",
          caseSensitive: false,
          multiLine: false,
        );

        print("10.5 : "+regExp.hasMatch("10.5").toString());
        print("-10.5 : "+regExp.hasMatch("-10.5").toString());
        print("0.5 : " +regExp.hasMatch("0.5").toString());
        print("-0.5 : "+regExp.hasMatch("-0.5").toString());
        print("0 : " +regExp.hasMatch("0").toString());
```

None of these are working...

(Also anyone knows an online tool where I can generate regex based on given parameters?)

Comment: If you want to control inputs, use a dropdown or similar control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for instance https://regex101.com for testing and validating regular expressions.

You must not escape the backslash for control characters like `\d`. In your case `\\d` literally expects the character `\` followed by the character `d`  So you should use `r"(.\d\d.\d)"` instead.

But also the pattern per se is wrong for many of your test cases

Your regex expects a string that

1. `.` starts with an arbitrary character
2. `\d\d` followd by exactly two digits
3. `.` again an aribtrary character
4. `\d` followed again by a single digit

Ie all accepted strings must have 3 characters before the decimal character (which can be anything), and two of them must be digits, and one digit after the decimal character

As you don't have any anchors `^` or `$` it will also match those patterns if they are embedded in a longer string

As for your test cases

- `0` is only a single digit, thus way too short
- `0.5` does not have 3 characters before the comma
- `1.5` does not have 3 characters before the comma
- `-10.5` would have been accepted, if you didn't use duplicate backslashes `\\`

So a valid regex for your usecase could be the following

```
r("^-?\d{1,2}(\.\d)?$")
```

- `^` and `$` match the beginning and the end of the string respectively. If you want to match expressions that are embedded in a longer string you can remove.
- `-?` matches an optional sign at the beginning
- `\d{1,2}` matches one or two digits. If you want an arbitrary number, you can also use `\d+` which matches any number of digits (at least one)
- `\.`  matches the decimal point `.` literally,
- `\d` matches a single digit
- `(\.\d)?` makes the decimal point + digit optional

Answer (score 1):

I hope something like this should work:

```
  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(
          r"\-?\d+(\.\d+)*",
          caseSensitive: false,
          multiLine: false,
        );

  print("10.5 : "+regExp.hasMatch("10.5").toString());
  print("-10.5 : "+regExp.hasMatch("-10.5").toString());
  print("0.5 : " +regExp.hasMatch("0.5").toString());
  print("-0.5 : "+regExp.hasMatch("-0.5").toString());
  print("0 : " +regExp.hasMatch("0").toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Temperature values have plus or minus in front. You must allow an optional sign before a number:

```js
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r"[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?");
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/HSiqju/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [-+]?                    any character of: '-', '+' (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
```